# Azure B2C - Different Branding for users based on email domains

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a requirement to have different users see different branding based on their email domain (part after the @ symbol). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I would create separate apps registration and user flows per domain. In that way you would be able to customize each branding separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use claims resolvers and dynamic page layouts with a custom policy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-dynamic-custom-page-content-uri

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview

That will allow you to pass the email or email suffix by claims resolver to your content definition loadURI URL. A web app should then parse the url query string when the request for html is made to it, and return html in respect to the email/suffix in the query param.

Comment: Thank you @Jas. Is there a sample I can take a look at? I am getting confused with the part where you mentioned a web app should parse the URL query string when the request for html is made to it. Can't we have the Load URI (after using claim resolvers to pass the email suffix) be an absolute path to the HTML in blob storage as usual? What purpose is parsing with the web app serving?

Comment: Also, which claim resolver type will you use? I am thinking {OIDC:DomainHint}, {OIDC:LoginHint}, or {Claim:claimType}.